# Azure mobile app offline sync with custom controller

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I'm using [Azure Mobile App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop) for developing back end APIs to consume SQL Server database, cause i want to use the Built-in feature called [Offline Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data) to work offline mode in my mobile client app.

So, i created API endpoints using `TableController`,

```
public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        SyncMobiAppContext context = new SyncMobiAppContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request);
    }        
}
```

and offline sync mode works perfect in mobile client. But when i use `[MobileAppController]` attribute which technically [derived](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Configuring-MobileAppController-and-TableController-Settings) from `TableController` to create API endpoints,

```
// Use the MobileAppController attribute for each ApiController you want to use  
// from your mobile clients 
[MobileAppController]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {         
        using (var context = new SyncMobiDBEntities())
        {
            return context.Customers.Select(x => x.FirstName).ToArray();
        }
    }        
}
```

offline sync won't works.

Is there any way to implement or support the Offline Sync feature in client SDK using `[MobileAppController]` attribute APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I known, `ApiController` just defines properties and methods for API controller. While `TableController` inherits from `ApiController` and provides the new features(CURD operations on tables in Azure Mobile Apps by using EF data context, offline sync,etc).

As mentioned in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller) about `MobileAppController`:

> The MobileAppController attribute registers the route, sets up the Mobile Apps JSON serializer, and turns on client version checking.

In general, if you want offline sync and client-side simple querying features, I assume that you need to use a `TableController`.